# Prepending a null row to DataTable that does not allow nulls

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, datatables

I have a drop-down menu in my web application that is data-bound to a DataTable. I want to make the first item in the drop-down list blank and be the first thing in the list. I am trying to do this by inserting a new DataRow where the text value is `""` and the primary key value is `DBNull.Value` because I want the blank to raise an SQL exception if it is submitted. However if I try to insert this row I get a `NoNullAllowedException`.
I've tried `myTable.PrimaryKey = null;` and `myTable.Constraints.Clear();` but no luck.
Is there a way around this? Or maybe even a better way to do this?

EDIT: for clarity I do understand that raising exceptions for validation is bad, and it's not for that. I want it to raise an exception in the case someone forgets to validate the input before sending it off to the database.

Comment: You need to enable dbnull per Datacolumn

Comment: Why don't you just have it's value set to "-1" or something then check for that prior to your SQL?  P.S.  Throwing exceptions is a bad way for data validation.  Exceptions should be used to cope with situation where things did not go as expected, whether it's to abort, write to a log file, display an error, etc. They should not be used to validate information that is expected.

Comment: Add the blank item to the Drop Down Menu itself, not to the Data Table. If you are using the DropDownList item, there's an "AppendDataBoundItems" property you can set to TRUE. Add your blank value and then it will append your data table items during the data bind.

Comment: Would you add more information to your question: What ASP.NET control are you using? DropDownList? Menu? A custom control? Posting some of your code would help too.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck please make a full answer so I can mark it as accepted